# Problem in rerender

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I am facing problem in rerendering the treepanel when I select value from selectlist.The jsonstring in the controller is right but it is not reflecting in jstree.

Below is the code.
Please help on how to fix this.

```
 <apex:page controller="customcontroller" sidebar="false" id="page">

        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquerymin}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jstree, '/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css')}"/>
        <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jstree, '/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js')}"></script>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.AlignmaxCommonCSS}"/>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            createTree();
        });
            function createTree(){
                var j$=jQuery.noConflict();
                j$(function(){
                j$('#jstree').jstree({

                        "core" : {
                        "check_callback" : true,
                        "themes" : { "stripes" : true },        
                        'data' : {!jsonString}

                        }
                   }); 

                });
                alert('inside tree Json String'+JSON.stringify({!jsonString}));
            }
        </script>
        <apex:form id="form">
          <div class="box-main">


            <div class="box-content">
                <apex:actionStatus startText=" (Shant Baitho...!!!)" stopText="" id="processingStatus" />
                <apex:actionFunction name="TreeRefresh"   status="processingStatus" action="{!processTeam}"  rerender="treePanel" />
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTeam}" size="1" style="width:20%;" onchange="TreeRefresh();" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TeamList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
                <div class="tree">
                    Tree Structure 
                    <apex:outputPanel id="treePanel">
                        <div id="jstree"> </div>  
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </apex:form>
        </apex:page>
```

Controller Code

```
public class Customcontroller{
    public String jsonString{get;set;}
    public String rootGeographyId {get; set;} 
    public static String selectedTeam{get;set;}
    public Customcontroller()
    {
        rootGeographyId = [ Select Id From Territory__c where name= 'D' ].Id ;
        jsonString = GeographyUtilForAcco.getTreeJSON(rootGeographyId,selectedTeam);  
        system.debug('--JSON String in Alignmax Constructor---'+jsonString);  
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getTeamList(){
        List<SelectOption> tList = new List<SelectOption>();
        tList.add(new SelectOption('Select Team','Select Team'));
        for(Team__c t : [Select Name from Team__c])
        {
            tList.add(new SelectOption(t.Name,t.Name));
        }
        return tList;
    }
    public void processTeam()
    {
        jsonString = GeographyUtilForAcco.getTreeJSON(rootGeographyId,selectedTeam);
        system.debug('--JSON String in Alignmax Controller---'+jsonString);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your relevant controller code, or at least `processTeam()`

Comment: Where is your reRender tag?

Comment: Added the controller and rerender tag

Answer (score 0):

You're rerendering the panel but not updating the tree.  Try adding `createTree()` as the `oncomplete` attribute of the `actionFunction`

```
<apex:actionFunction name="TreeRefresh" status="processingStatus" action="{!processTeam}" rerender="treePanel" oncomplete="createTree()" />
```